# Joint Exponential Distribution, Memoryless property

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution

[image]

Part (a) is ok, but I don't know how to express the distribution of O = max{X,Y} - min{X,Y}.

Is it correct to use an integral in part b and then evaluate it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The event $\{W \le w, M=1, O \le t\}$ requires $X \le Y$ and so $W=X$ and $Z=Y$ leading to $X \le Y \le X+t$ and $X \le w$.

Comment: Given memorylessness, $P(O \le t \mid M=1)= P(Y \le t)$.